# How to inherit context from calling function, or create new one if it doesn't exist?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, contextmanager

I have an instance of `Session` from `sqlalchemy.orm` that's being managed by Python's `with` keyword.

```py
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session

def save_child(child):
    with Session() as session, session.begin():
        parent = child.parent 
        db_parent = save_parent(parent, session=session)
```

And I'd like to call another function `save_parent()` from within the context manager. The thing is that I'd like that function to operate with or without an existing context.

Is there a pythonic way of doing something like:

```py
def save_parent(parent, session=None):
    if session:
        # Use existing session
    else: 
        # create a new one
```

? Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at `contextlib.nullcontext`.

Comment: Or possibly `contextlib.ExitStack`, for conditionally adding a context to the initially empty.